# SonarQube. The user loses his rights during a new session

Tags: active-directory, sonarqube

The problem is that users in the administrators group lose their rights after logging out of the SonarQube account. I assign them manually, but it can happen again. Sonar is installed for Linux. Sonar version - 9.3

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someday it will be useful to someone. The problem was in the LDAP configuration.

Correct configuration:

```
ldap.user.request=(&(sAMAccountName={login})(objectClass=user))

ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=group)(member={dn}))
```